# Create a data.frame where a column is a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I know how to add a list column:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:3)
> df$b <- list(1:1, 1:2, 1:3)
> df
  a       b
1 1       1
2 2    1, 2
3 3 1, 2, 3
```

This works, but not:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=list(1:1, 1:2, 1:3))
Error in data.frame(1L, 1:2, 1:3, check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 3
```

Why?

Also, is there a way to create `df` (above) in a single call to `data.frame`?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Slightly obscurely, from `?data.frame`:

> If a list or data frame or matrix is passed to ‘data.frame’ it is as
> if each component or column had been passed as a separate argument
> (except for matrices of class ‘"model.matrix"’ **and those protected by
> ‘I’**).

(emphasis added).

So

```
data.frame(a=1:3,b=I(list(1,1:2,1:3)))
```

seems to work.

Comment: For those interested, "I" means "Inhibit Interperetation/Conversion of objects".  It creates an identical object but with "AsIs" appended to the set of classes.  The "AsIs" class is really there just to be read by the data.frame() and formula() functions.  Learn more [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/AsIs.html).

Comment: amazing, thanks for the solution. though just `I` for Inhibit Interperetation/Conversion of objects seems a bit too short :)

Comment: @pwilcox very interesting. Is there some method to call on an object to understand if it's protected by I? I guess it's `class()` ? e.g. `I(iris) -> i; i %>% class() 3 [1] "AsIs"       "data.frame"` (returns AsIs class)

Comment: @stevec See [GKi's recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69072292/6574038), it's IMO much better.

Comment: Could be worth adding that you can also assign a list column after the data frame creation: `df$b <- list(1,1:2, 1:3)`.

Answer (score 41):

If you are working with `data.tables`, then you can avoid the call to `I()`

```
library(data.table)
# the following works as intended
data.table(a=1:3,b=list(1,1:2,1:3))

   a     b
1: 1     1
2: 2   1,2
3: 3 1,2,3
```

Comment: This is an underappreciated feature of ```data.table``` by a wide margin

Answer (score 27):

`data_frame`s (variously called `tibbles`, `tbl_df`, `tbl`) natively support the creation of list columns using the `data_frame` constructor. To use them, load one of the many libraries with them such as [`tibble`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/24/tibble-1-0-0/), `dplyr` or `tidyverse`.

```
> data_frame(abc = letters[1:3], lst = list(1:3, 1:3, 1:3))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    abc       lst
  <chr>    <list>
1     a <int [3]>
2     b <int [3]>
3     c <int [3]>
```

They are actually `data.frames` under the hood, but somewhat modified. They can almost always be used as normal `data.frames`. The only exception I've found is that when people do inappropriate class checks, they cause problems:

```
> #no problem
> data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3) %>% class
[1] "data.frame"
> data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3) %>% class == "data.frame"
[1] TRUE
> #uh oh
> data_frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3) %>% class
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> data_frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3) %>% class == "data.frame"
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> #dont use if with improper testing!
> if(data_frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3) %>% class == "data.frame") "something"
Warning message:
In if (data_frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3) %>% class == "data.frame") "something" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> #proper
> data_frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3) %>% inherits("data.frame")
[1] TRUE
```

I recommending reading about them in *[R 4 Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html)* (free).

Comment: R is moving and growing and I think this is the 2018 answer to the question and somehow it should be marked as such.

Comment: If it is popular enough it will rise to the top.  A lot of us still use base R ...

Answer (score 7):

You can use `list2DF` to *create a `data.frame` where a column is a `list`*.

```
x <- list2DF(list(a=1:3, b=list(1:1, 1:2, 1:3)))
#x <- data.frame(a=1:3, list2DF(list(b=list(1:1, 1:2, 1:3)))) #Alternative

x
#  a       b
#1 1       1
#2 2    1, 2
#3 3 1, 2, 3

str(x)
#'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: int  1 2 3
# $ b:List of 3
#  ..$ : int 1
#  ..$ : int  1 2
#  ..$ : int  1 2 3
```

With this you don't have the `attr` `AsIs` in the `data.frame`, what you would have when using `I`.

Answer (score 1):

### tibble >= 1.1.0

[As of July 2016](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#tibble-11), [`tibble()`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tibble.html) and [`as_tibble()`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/as_tibble.html) became preferred over `data_frame()` and `as_data_frame()` within the tidyverse.

```r
library(tibble)

tibble(a = 1:3, b = list(1:1, 1:2, 1:3))

# create tibble row-wise
tribble(~ a, ~ b,
        1, list(1:1),
        2, list(1:2),
        3, list(1:3))
```

These functions are imported by many popular tidyverse packages such as `dplyr`.