# R vector values in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and would like to add a new column where the values are vectors. 
Is this possible in R?

Thanks,

Comment: `transform`, `with`, `within`, `$`, `[` are all ways to add a new column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store a list as part of a data frame, which is one way to have vector-valued entries. For example:

```
m <- data.frame(a=1:10)
m$l <- lapply(1:10, function(x) c(x, x + 1))
m$l
```

As an example of how this is actually used in R, a `POSIXlt` date is actually a list with components giving the year, month, day, and so on. When you store such a date variable in a data frame, what is stored is a list of vectors.

Comment: +1 - also, if you want the column to be included as part of the call to the `data.frame()` "constructor", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547518/creating-a-data-frame-where-a-column-is-a-list

Comment: now we need it to be read from a `csv` file somehow and that would be grand :)