# How can vectors be used in dataframe columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, indexing

Is there any way to do something like this in R without having 6 samples but just 2?

```
> df <- data.frame(w=c(1,2),x=c('asdf','yxcv'), y=c(1234, 5678), z=c(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7,8)))
> df
  w    x    y z
1 1 asdf 1234 1
2 2 yxcv 5678 2
3 1 asdf 1234 3
4 2 yxcv 5678 4
5 1 asdf 1234 5
6 2 yxcv 5678 6
7 1 asdf 1234 7
8 2 yxcv 5678 8
```

I would like to and get and be able to use a vector when I do something like:

```
> df$z[1]
[1] 1 2 3 4
> sum(df$z[1])
[1] 10
```

Or get the following when selecting a row:

```
> df[1,]
  w    x    y  z
1 1 asdf 1234  c(1,2,3,4)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866296/r-vector-values-in-dataframe) post does something similar but does not resolve the problem of using the vectors as vectors.

Comment: Try using `list` instead of `c` in your definition of column `z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the answer in the link you provided. Just note that `lapply` returns an object of class `"list"`. All you need to do is to create a dataframe without the final column `z` and assign a list to that column.

```
df <- data.frame(w=c(1,2),x=c('asdf','yxcv'), y=c(1234, 5678))
df$z <- list(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7,8))
```

Now it works as requested.

```
df
#  w    x    y          z
#1 1 asdf 1234 1, 2, 3, 4
#2 2 yxcv 5678 5, 6, 7, 8
```

Extraction. Note [the difference between `[` and `[[`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-elem).

```
df$z[1]
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

df$z[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

And operations on the list members.

```
sum(df$z[1])
#Error in sum(df$z[1]) : 'type' inválido (list) do argumento

sum(df$z[[1]])
#[1] 10
```