# Check list in data.frame contains element

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data.frame, where one column is a list (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547518/creating-a-data-frame-where-a-column-is-a-list)) I would like to check which lists within the data.frame contain an element (let's say the number 3) Currently, I am looping through all rows of the data.frame.

```
df=data.frame(a=1:3,b=I(list(1,3:7,1:3)))
df
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
     print(3 %in% df$b[[i]])

}
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You could use `apply(df, 1, function(x) 3 %in% unlist(x[2]))` which loops also, but perhaps 'elegant.'

Comment: I would go with ```mapply(`%in%`, 3, df$b)``` or `sapply(df$b, function(x) 3 %in% x)` or something similar

Comment: That surely is more elegant. I had not used `mapply` before. Very nice.

Comment: If you have a working solution but want to know what would've been better, then that's a question for Code Review rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
3 %in% unlist(df$b)
```

The result:

```
> 3 %in% unlist(df$b)
[1] TRUE
```

Unlist(df$b) concatenates all the elements of df$b into a vector.

If you have multiple columns:

```
> apply(df,2,function(x) 3 %in% unlist(x))
   a    b 
TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: I guess they were looking for a result by row (for column "b"). Your solution only tells if 3 appeared anywehere in a column

Comment: Yes, they were looking for a result for specifically column "b". I'm aware that the second solution for multiple columns looks for 3 anywhere in the column regardless of whether the column contains a list. He will have to subset the columns first.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like using map to solve a problem like this, more information can be found [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/lists.html).

```
library(purrr)
df %>% transpose() %>% map(2) %>% map((function(x) 3 %in% x))
```

which gives:

```
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE
```

Alternatively, there is also *map_lgl* which returns a logical array rather than a list.

```
df %>% transpose() %>% map(2) %>% map_lgl((function(x) 3 %in% x))
```

which give:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```