# Adding multiple random forest models into a single data frame or data table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning

I am training multiple 'treebag' models in R.  I loop through a data set, where each iteration I define a specific subset based on a feature in the set and train on that subset.  I could save each result to disk, but I was hoping to save all the models to a single data frame or data table.  I am not sure if this is at all possible.  The data frame/table could have numerous classes (numeric and character), however I would like to add a completed model.

To start, is it even possible to assign multiple models to a single column, where each model is assigned to a different row in a data frame or data table?

Any ideas on how this could work is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can assign output to a data frame.  You can the model object to a list, possibly to a column in a data frame. You have a variety of options. When you say save all models, do you mean the model object (fit) or the model's output (fit$finalModel)?

Comment: you should learn about lists

Comment: Thanks - I have multiple models to a list before, but I was thinking of assigning it directly to the data frame instead.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547518/create-a-data-frame-where-a-column-is-a-list

Comment: Also, I was thinking of adding all the components of the finished model object, but in reality I may only need the one component.  Based on Ryan's comment - is that fit$finalModel?  Could the rest be stripped away and the model remains functional?

Comment: I think the model must retain the whole object to be used later.  If you were doing a regression model, you could extract the coefficients from the model and use those to construct your model elsewhere - I don't think RF could work that way.

Comment: Thanks Ryan,I think I am just going to add additional fields to the model to store the data and then save the models to disk, labelling them with a different name.  I wanted to attach a few other reference data points such as length of time model ran, feature importance using varImp() and confusion matrix.  It appears I can just attach this data to the model.  Appreciate the help here.