# Is it possible to put lists/vectors of variable lengths in a column of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

Say I've got a list of various character vectors, with lengths between 0 and 10. I want to turn this into a column of a dataframe. Is this possible?

Comment: please be more explicit with your expected output. yes, list columns are possible.

Comment: List columns sound like what I'm looking for. How do you make them?

Comment: you assign them just like you would any other column, as long as `length(l)==nrow(DF)`

Comment: Found a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547518/create-a-data-frame-where-a-column-is-a-list) using `I()`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, with `tibble::tibble()` it is, the only complication being that columns that are not of length 1 or 10 (in your case) will have to be list-columns. For example:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(
  first = list(rep("a", 6)),
  second = list(rep("b", 7)),
  third = list(rep("c", 4)),
  fourth = rep("d", 10)
)
```

Result:

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
       first    second     third fourth
      <list>    <list>    <list>  <chr>
 1 <chr [6]> <chr [7]> <chr [4]>      d
 2 <chr [6]> <chr [7]> <chr [4]>      d
 3 <chr [6]> <chr [7]> <chr [4]>      d
 4 <chr [6]> <chr [7]> <chr [4]>      d
 5 <chr [6]> <chr [7]> <chr [4]>      d
 6 <chr [6]> <chr [7]> <chr [4]>      d
 7 <chr [6]> <chr [7]> <chr [4]>      d
 8 <chr [6]> <chr [7]> <chr [4]>      d
 9 <chr [6]> <chr [7]> <chr [4]>      d
10 <chr [6]> <chr [7]> <chr [4]>      d
```

If you had literally a list of character vectors, you could put them into a column in a tibble with `c()`.