# How to mutate a vector to the end of each line in a dataframe via dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

As expected, this code

```
myLines="
Greek
alpha
beta
gamma
"
myData <- read.table(text=myLines, header=TRUE)
print(myData)
```

produces:

```
  Greek
1 alpha
2  beta
3 gamma
```

I now want to mutate the vector c(1,2,3,4) to the end of each row in order to get this:

```
  Greek justSomeVector
1 alpha     c(1,2,3,4)
2  beta     c(1,2,3,4)
3 gamma     c(1,2,3,4)
```

So I tried this:

```
library(dplyr)
myData=myData%>%mutate(justSomeVector=c(1,2,3,4))
```

And this yields this error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `justSomeVector` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 4
```

How do I have to change my code in order to make the mutation work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547518/create-a-data-frame-where-a-column-is-a-list ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to list the list of numbers, or else it will mutate as if the `justSomeVector` is a vector that needs to be spread along the rows

```
myData=myData%>%mutate(justSomeVector=list(c(1,2,3,4)))
#  Greek justSomeVector
#1 alpha     1, 2, 3, 4
#2  beta     1, 2, 3, 4
#3 gamma     1, 2, 3, 4
```